# Optimize coordinates distance calculation

Tags: java, android, performance, optimization

Hi guys i need help optimizing my distance calculation.
After some time may be minutes may be hours depends on the phone it slows it down and the app can barely work i have narrowed it down to the distance calculation but i dont know how to fix it.
I converted all of the oter decimal numbers in the app to float and that helped a little but i need the distance in double.
Here is the code

`double getTripDistance(List vertices) {

```
    double totalDistance = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size() - 1; i++) {
        Location tLoc1 = new Location("");
        Location tLoc2 = new Location("");

        tLoc1.setLatitude(vertices.get(i).latitude);
        tLoc1.setLongitude(vertices.get(i).longitude);

        tLoc2.setLatitude(vertices.get(i + 1).latitude);
        tLoc2.setLongitude(vertices.get(i + 1).longitude);

        totalDistance += tLoc1.distanceTo(tLoc2);
    }
    return totalDistance;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a `List vertices` and compute the distance based on that list from scratch every time. Rather you should track the `overallDistance` and as soon as a new `vertex` is added to the `vertices` list you take that one and the previous entry in the list, calculate the distance between those two and add the result onto the already existing `overallDistance`.

Pseudo code:

```
class Trip {
    List vertices;
    double distance;

    addVertex(vertex) {
        last = vertices.getLast()
        vertices.add(vertex)
        if last {
             distance += distanceBetween(vertex, last)
        }
    }

    getTripDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im sorry im new to vertices can you edit and write the code this pseudo code doesnt help me.

Comment: @Dino no. This code is completely decoupled from any vertices, what they are, how they behave, etc. You already wrote the code to calculate the distances between two of them in your question, just plug that in at the right location